# How to merge two parallel branches in a Git repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I have a project for which there was no `Git` repository, so I created one for it in `Gitlab`. At the time of repo creation, I had two folders, one containting the production code and one containing the development code.

I created a local `git` repo in the folder containing the production code. I pushed the code to the remote `master` of the repository which I initially created.

I then created a local `git` repo in the folder containing the development code. I created a new local branch (let's say xyz) from local master. I pushed this new local branch `xyz` to the same remote repository.

The remote repository now has `master` branch and the `xyz` branch. Now, I want to merge the `xyz` branch to the `master` as I am finished with the development.

But as I was trying to be oversmart, I have two parallel branches with unrelated histories in the same repository. One solution could be to delete the repository and start fresh with the new code which I just finished with but is there any way to preserve the old code and also merge these branches?

Comment: I suggest you look at `git rebase`. If I have time later, I will write up a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a single revision in master (or it could be many revisions, doesn't matter) with last production environment.... then you have a branch that is parallel to master where from the very first revision is a continuation of master. is that right? So if we were able to put the first (oldest) revision of xyz (the content of that revision) on top of master and then replay all the other revisions following the first revision of xyz, you would be happy right?

Ok... if that's the case:

```
git checkout first-revision-xyz # check out the first revision of xyz
git reset --soft master # set the branch pointer on top of the current position of master (master won't be touched, don't worry)
git commit -m "taking back content to how it is on the first revision of xyz" # create a new revision, set appropriate comment
git cherry-pick first-revision-of-xyz..xyz # replay all the other revisions up to the last revision of xyz
# if you like the result
git checkout -b development
```

There you created branch development, it follows master, you could then start playing with it as usual.

As a different strategy, you might want to merge both branches but keeping the tree (files and content) as it is on xyz? That can be done without going through a real merge process.

```
git checkout -b test $( git commit-tree -p master -p xyz -m "Merge of prod an development" ${xyz^tree} )

Created a test branch that has the merge of both branches keeping the tree as it is on xyz.
```

Comment: Yeah you understood it correct. I need to try your solution now.

Comment: After  1+ year, I noticed a little detail that was not correct in the recipe, though the general concept is correct. I adjusted the recipe